# 2 layouts in one controller

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have in my HomeController.php

```
   // other pages layout
protected $layout = "layout";

protected $layout2 = "layout2";
    // empty user object
protected $user;

// constructor
public function __construct() 
{ 
}


public function getAbout()
{

// share main home page only
 $this->layout->content = View::make('about');

}

// THIS IS NOT WORKING >>>>
public function getAboutnew()
{

// share main home page only
 $this->layout2->content = View::make('about');

}
```

so the `getAboutNew` I am trying to use layout2 but I am getting an error:

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Attempt to assign property of non-object

How to fix this?

Comment: $this->layout2 is a string, not an object.

Comment: how come $this->layout is an object and that one works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes to your `BaseController` from which your `HomeController` is extending.
In your `BaseController` you have:

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

This converts the `$this->layout` (string) into the view object that you need.

**Fix:**

```
// BaseController, returning respective views for layouts
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }

    if ( ! is_null($this->layout2))
    {
        $this->layout2 = View::make($this->layout2);
    }
}



// HomeController
public function getAbout()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('about');
}


public function getAboutnew()
{
     $this->layout2->content = View::make('about');
     return $this->layout2;
     // Note the additional return above.
     //You need to do this whenever your layout is not the default $this->layout
}
```